# How can I get more than one character to show in a messagebox from a textbox user input?

Tags: winforms, textbox, messagebox

I have made a textbox and I want the user to type in a string of numbers and hit enter. I have setup the following:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String UserBarcode;

    Focus();
    UserBarcode = Console.ReadLine();
    MessageBox.Show(UserBarcode);
}
```

When I enter any key into the textbox, I get a message box with nothing in it. I want to have the program wait til it hears the enter key then display the contents of the textbox.

Comment: Why are you trying to read from the console instead of getting the value of the textbox? Is this WPF?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms Editor. Your comment makes be think that "console" is the wrong read element for this. What is the correct one?

Comment: Look for the Enter key in the text box's KeyDown event, then reference the textBox1.Text property for your value.  Console is the wrong project type.  Your question begs you to get a tutorial book.

Comment: I am new to this. I did several tutorials with the console application and it isnt translating well into windows forms. Ive tried this:        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String UserBarcode;

            Focus();//When the program starts place the cursor in this textbox
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                UserBarcode = textBox1.Text;
                MessageBox.Show(UserBarcode);

            } but I get an error about the KeyCode not being defined.

Comment: This is my first attempt at making a program and I feel like I am installing Linux for the first time before Ubuntu came out with a live cd. This is only the first step in my program and I cannot even get it to do something as simple as read the data from a text box and output it to a message box. This is ridiculous. I appreciate your help. I tried to code it myself and when I couldnt get it I added the code you gave me and it errored out and I researched it and messaged you back with the errors I got and I posted your fix and Im getting this.

Comment: I have deleted my code 4 times and restarted from scratch and only added what you offered and I am still getting an error. I just dont get it. If I add your code from a brand new untouched Windows Forms Application then why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

The `Textbox.TextChanged` event fires as soon as the text in the textbox is changed at all. If you want a message box with the full string, you probably want to consider using the `Textbox.LostFocus` event or a button's `Click` event.

So you could have something like (I'm taking a stab at this here, as I've used VB rather than C#)

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sender.Text)
}
```

If you're using a button, the above function should work, but you'll want to substitute `textBox1.Text` for `sender.Text`.

Comment: This is useful. Instead of a click event how can I make the event the enter key?

Comment: I actually don't know, since I haven't used KeyDown events before. I'd take a look at LarsTech's comment on your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Focus and Validation Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are several events that you can handle, depending on your goals and how your application is designed. If you want to perform validation and/or are using data binding, you may want to go with handling the validating/validated events. By default data bindings update a bound property after OnValidating. If you use LostFocus and read the value from a bound object, instead of your control, you will get inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out finally. For some reason when I manually entered the code I kept getting multiple random errors. I started a new Visual C # Windows Forms Application, Made a textbox, chose the keydown property and double clicked on it to have the program inject the code for the keydown function and then I filled in the if statement pointing to the enter key. The final code looks like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
    }  
}
```